# How to change the header and footer on my website?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Website name is newinternetdaily.com
So yesterday i installed newsmag cracked theme for website . It has options for changing header but the default text is not getting changed .
I don't know php so help me in editing the header text and footer.
code of header.php

```
<!doctype html >
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' );?>" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <?php
    wp_head(); /** we hook up in wp_booster @see td_wp_booster_functions::hook_wp_head */
    ?>
</head>


<body <?php body_class() ?> itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="<?php echo td_global::$http_or_https?>://schema.org/WebPage">

<?php //this is closing in the footer.php file ?>
<div id="td-outer-wrap">

    <?php /* scroll to top */?>
    <div class="td-scroll-up"><i class="td-icon-menu-up"></i></div>

    <div class="td-transition-content-and-menu td-mobile-nav-wrap">
        <?php locate_template('parts/menu-mobile.php', true);?>
    </div>

    <?php //this is closing in the footer.php file ?>
    <div class="td-transition-content-and-menu td-content-wrap">



<?php
td_api_header_style::_helper_show_header();


do_action('td_wp_booster_after_header'); //used by unique articles



 And the footer.php file is 

    <!-- Footer -->
    <?php
        if (td_util::get_option('tds_footer') != 'no') {
            td_api_footer_template::_helper_show_footer();
        }
    ?>
<!-- Sub Footer -->
<?php if (td_util::get_option('tds_sub_footer') != 'no') { ?>
    <div class="td-sub-footer-container td-container td-container-border <?php if (td_util::get_option('tds_footer') == 'no' && td_util::get_option('tds_footer_bottom_color') == '' ) { echo "td-add-border";} ?>">
        <div class="td-pb-row">
            <div class="td-pb-span4 td-sub-footer-copy">
                <div class="td-pb-padding-side">
                    <?php
                    $tds_footer_copyright = td_util::get_option('tds_footer_copyright');
                    $tds_footer_copy_symbol = td_util::get_option('tds_footer_copy_symbol');

                    //show copyright symbol
                    if ($tds_footer_copy_symbol == '') {
                        echo '&copy; ';
                    }

                    echo $tds_footer_copyright;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="td-pb-span8 td-sub-footer-menu">
                <div class="td-pb-padding-side">
                    <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(array(
                        'theme_location' => 'footer-menu',
                        'menu_class'=> '',
                        'fallback_cb' => 'td_wp_footer_menu'
                    ));

                    //if no menu
                    function td_wp_footer_menu() {
                        //do nothing?
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
    </div><!--close content div-->
</div><!--close td-outer-wrap-->



<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which text do you need to change?

Comment: newsmag and its description

Answer (score 1):

Go to wordpress dashboard, click on **Newsmag>Theme panel**, under themepanel click on **header** then go to **Logo & Favicon**.
Ther you will find **Text Logo and Text Logo Tagline**, here you can change.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code id `<head></head>` section, and change background

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var text = "Rainbow Text";
var speed = 80;

if (document.all || document.getElementById) {
    document.write('<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" id="highlight">' + text + '<\/span>');
    var storetext = document.getElementById ? document.getElementById("highlight") : document.all.highlight;
} else
    document.write(text);

var hex = new Array("00", "14", "28", "3C", "50", "64", "78", "8C", "A0", "B4", "C8", "DC", "F0");
var r = 1;
var g = 1;
var b = 1;
var seq = 1;

function changetext() {
    rainbow = "#" + hex[r] + hex[g] + hex[b];
    storetext.style.color = rainbow;
}

function change() {
    if (seq == 6) {
        b--;
        if (b == 0)
            seq = 1;
    }
    if (seq == 5) {
        r++;
        if (r == 12)
            seq = 6;
    }
    if (seq == 4) {
        g--;
        if (g == 0)
            seq = 5;
    }
    if (seq == 3) {
        b++;
        if (b == 12)
            seq = 4;
    }
    if (seq == 2) {
        r--;
        if (r == 0)
            seq = 3;
    }
    if (seq == 1) {
        g++;
        if (g == 12)
            seq = 2;
    }
    changetext();
}

function starteffect() {
    if (document.all || document.getElementById)
        flash = setInterval("change()", speed);
}
starteffect();


</script>
```

Comment: Amit This is not the place to get back link. In every answer you are pasting irrelevant code with backlink. Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563488/addthis-jquery-sharing-buttons-for-wordpress-how-to-animate/34565522#34565522) Please do not do it.