# addThis Sharing Buttons for Wordpress, how to animate?

Tags: css, wordpress, addthis

I'm looking for a plugin/code that can give some nice mouse hover animation over `addThis` share buttons, but still want to enjoy the 1-click tweet,like,etc. feature of `addThis` default buttons.

The one i have now is default, looks like,

[image: Default]

What i want is something similar to the one used in [arduino.cc](https://blog.arduino.cc/2015/12/15/you-can-build-arduino-multi-device-networks-with-temboo/) blog, the default 1-click buttons are hidden by default and get visible only on mouse hover.
eg:-

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this placing custom Images with actual sharing buttons together.
Keep all the sharing button width 0 by default and make them visible on hover by increasing width.
Also add CSS transition to expend the buttons smoothly.

Consider this example.

```css
.sharing-buttons {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.share-button {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0;
}
.sharing-buttons:hover .share-button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="sharing-buttons fb">
    <a href="#">Custom Image</a>
    <div class="share-button">Button iframe</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sharing-buttons tw">
    <a href="#">Custom Image</a>
    <div class="share-button">Button iframe</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Final addThis code & CSS

```css
.addthis_toolbox a.at300b, .addthis_toolbox a.at300m {
 padding: 5px;
 width: auto;
}

.social-container {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width:auto;
}

.social-content {
 float: right;
 margin-left: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 -moz-transition: max-width .3s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition: max-width .3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: max-width .3s ease-out;
 transition: max-width .3s ease-out;
 white-space: nowrap;
 max-width: 0;
}

.social-container:hover .social-content {
 -moz-transition: max-width .2s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition: max-width .2s ease-in;
 -o-transition: max-width .2s ease-in;
 transition: max-width .2s ease-in;
 max-width: 95px;
}
```

```html
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <!-- FACEBOOK -->
    <div class="social-container">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="" />
      <div class="social-content">
          <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like at300b" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- G+ -->
    <div class="social-container">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/gplus.png" alt="" />
      <div class="social-content">
        <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="large"></a> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- TWITTER -->
    <div class="social-container">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/twitter.png" alt="" />
      <div class="social-content">
        <a class="addthis_button_tweet at300b"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Animation seems good, But, Sorry to say, it's still not solved my problem. Now i'm stuck at adding an image and wrapping it in a div for each button created by 
<?php do_action( 'addthis_widget', get_permalink(), get_the_title());?>

Comment: I am sorry to say but this site mean to help people with code not to do their code.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding caused, I have mentioned it in my question that i'm trying get animation over my existing #addThis share buttons.

Comment: AddThis is not only the WordPress plugin it can be used in any website. Check here [AddThis | Third Party Buttons](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381237-third-party-buttons) For WordPress you need to try this with yourself when stuck ask another question with code and problems.